# creating new object from with the init function of another object

Tags: javascript

Inside the init function of an object I'm creating I want to create a new instance of another object.

At the moment my init code looks like this:

```
    var myObj = {

getData: function(){

      var instance = this;

      // Display preloader gif
      instance.selectors.preloader.fadeIn();

      // Make call for appropriate data */
      dataManager.feed.get( function(data){

        for( var i = 0, len = data.feed.length; i < len; i++ ){

          var template = '';

        }
      }, window, null, '' );

      instance.displayVideos();

    },

    init: function(){

          var instance = this;

          // Create new DataManager object
          var dataManager = new DataManager();
    }



    }
```

myObj.init();

My problem is that I get an error telling me that DataManager is not defined, can anyone explain how I reference this object?

Comment: But `DataManager` *is* undefined in your example.

Comment: It also looks like you're using [Closure](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/closure/goog/docs/closure_goog_datasource_datamanager.js.html) and you forgot to include the files necessary, which would explain the DataManager being `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, your code might be salvageable, but it's going to be hellish to maintain. I'd therefore suggest you use a closure, where you can *prep* your object as much as you want, before finally exposing it:

```
var myObj = (function(current)
{
    'use strict';//<-- not necessary, but highly recommended
    var instance = {};//<-- this is going to become the value myObj references
    //if you want the init method, make a function object
    var init = function()
    {
        instance.dataManager = new DataManager();
    };
    instance.init = init;//<-- make it "public"
    //alternatively:
    instance.dataManager = new DataManager();
    //OR to have access to an instance of the DataManager object, but as a 
    // "private" property:
    var dataManager = new DataManager();
    //All methods or functions declared in this scope will have access to this object, 
    // the outer scope won't!
    //same for getData, use either one of the following:
    var getData = function()
    {
        //refer to the instance, not by using this, but use instance var
        //which is safer, and immutable thanks to the closure we're building
    };
    instance.getData = getData;
    //OR:
    instance.getData = function()
    {
        //same function body, just created and assigned directly
    };
    //if you chose to use the init method:
    instance.init();
    //if you created an init function, but didn't assign it to the instance object:
    init();
    //when the instance object is all set up and good to go:
    return instance;//will be assigned to the myObj variable
}(this));//call function and pass current scope as argument
```

Then, there's just this piece of code that I *really* don't get:

```
dataManager.feed.get( function(data)
{
    //...
    for( var i = 0, len = data.feed.length; i < len; i++ )
    {//loop through an array of sorts
         var template = '';//and initialize a variable to an empty string each time?
    }
}, window, null, '' );
```

Why? What's the point, or is this just a dummy loop?

---

The way I see it, there are 2 major issues here. The first being you failed to include the `DataManager` constructor function. Assuming that constructor *is* defined in your code:

```
var myObj = {
    init: function()
    {
        var instance = this;
        // Create new DataManager object
        var dataManager = new DataManager();
    },
    myObj.init();//<== this can't work
};
```

You're calling a method of an object literal *while you're still defining it*. That doesn't work:

```
var myObj = {
    init: function()
    {
        var instance = this;
        // Create new DataManager object
        var dataManager = new DataManager();
    }
};
myObj.init();//<== now myObj exists, and has an init method
```

Comment: sorry that was actually a typo, i have the init method outside of myObj

Comment: In that case, is the `DataManager` constructor defined, and how is it defined? Do the cases match (remember that JS is Case Sensitive). If you defined it like so: `var DataManager = function(){}` your constructor is nameless, and merely referenced by the var `DataManager`, which complicates things. Therefore it would be better to include the constructor, too

Comment: Correct, but since functions are first class objects in js, you can pass it to the init method even if you have just a reference. Or you could scope it so it is globally available, but polluting the global space is bad.

Comment: @Asad: Those aren't the complications I was on about... The main thing is `myObj = {some:'literal',with: new Foo();}; var Foo = function(){this.instName = 'Foo';};` isn't going to work, because the constructor is defined in an expression, and isn't lifted to the top of the scope. Whereas `function Foo(){}` _is_ lifted to the top

Comment: So if he defined window.DataManager=function(){etc... return a datamanager object}, then initialised object with myObj.init(DataManager), assuming he had set a parameter, it wouldn't work?

Comment: No, it would, but if he were to do it the other way round, it wouldn't have worked. If he uses a constructor that is created by an expression (like an assignment) _before that expression is executed_ it'll fail. `var Foo = function(){this.name='bar';}; myObj{foo: new Foo()};` works, flip the order, and it'll fail. It's perfectly simple

Comment: @Asad: Just [test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/5SukF/) check the value of `obj`, then uncomment the first two lines and check what error is thrown

Comment: Oh you're talking about the order, right, sorry. I've pretty much been assuming DataManager is already defined somewhere (in an inaccessible scope) before he creates his object.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17696/discussion-between-asad-and-elias-van-ootegem)

Answer (score 0):

DataManager object should be defined before calling init() method.
I see one more problem within your code (). dataManager variable is not declared/assigned within getData() function. Use object level variable in this case. Try this : inside init method -

> init: function(){
>
> ```
>       var instance = this;
>
>       // Create new DataManager object
>       this.dataManager = new DataManager();  }
> ```

and inside getData() method use

> this.dataManager

instead of

> dataManager

.

Comment: Pankaj, in the question he is stating that the problem is DataManager is undefined, not dataManager, although you are probably right about his intention being to use the same dataManager property for all methods of myObj.

Comment: Yes Asad, thats right, I have edited the answer, actually I saw other people have answered about DataManager object's definition, so only pointed out other potential problem.